# Python NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Tags: python

Am starting in this, am gettin NameError: name 'message' is not defined this is the code:

```
message.attach(mime)

body = MIMEText('''
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Alert</h1>
        <h2>A new has Person entered the Premises</h2>
        <h2>Body Temperature: {}</h2>
        <h2>Mask: {}</h2>
        <h2>Time: {}</h2>
        <p>
            <img src="cid:0">
        </p>
    </body>
</html>'''.format(temp, mask, datetime.now()), 'html', 'utf-8')

# Add HTML/plain-text parts to MIMEMultipart message
# The email client will try to render the last part first
message.attach(body)
```

Comment: What is message supposed to be? (do you _define it_ anywhere?)

Comment: In python, variables come into existence when something is assigned to them. There is no assignment to `message` in the code posted so naturally its undefined. Show us the code where you assign `message` and we'll have something to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `NameError` tells you that there is no assignments on your code. So that you should assign what the `message` is.

The example code will be like this:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    
message = MIMEMultipart()    
message.attach(mime)
    
body = MIMEText('''
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Alert</h1>
        <h2>A new has Person entered the Premises</h2>
        <h2>Body Temperature: {}</h2>
        <h2>Mask: {}</h2>
        <h2>Time: {}</h2>
        <p>
            <img src="cid:0">
        </p>
    </body>
</html>'''.format(temp, mask, datetime.now()), 'html', 'utf-8')

# Add HTML/plain-text parts to MIMEMultipart message
# The email client will try to render the last part first
message.attach(body)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.